# Can you prove that the $\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})$ is equal to $\sqrt{\pi}$ without the gaussian integral/polar coordinates?

Tags: calculus

I've seen the product definition of gamma and thought it might work with that somehow? Want to prove it without the gaussian integral if possible.

Comment: [Your question should be clear without the title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/42969). After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: If you're fine with reducing it to the Gaussian integral but not using the polar coordinates trick to evaluate that interval, you could compute $\int_0^\infty x^{2n} e^{-x^2/2}$ for integers $n\geq 0$ in terms of $\Gamma(1/2)$ by integration by parts, then use that to write $\Gamma(1/2)$ in terms of $\int_0^\infty f(x)e^{-x^2/2}$ for convenient $f$ via a Taylor series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Euler's formula
$$
\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z)=\frac{\pi}{\sin\pi z}.
$$
Using this formula for $z=1/2$ gives the result.

Comment: That looks great, where can I find the proof for this formula? Thanks :)

Comment: @CormAlan https://mathoverflow.net/a/76423 is a short proof

Comment: Thanks!! That's all I needed :)

Comment: @AnthonyML: That particular proof *uses* the fact that $\Gamma(1/2) = \sqrt{\pi}$, so it would be circular to invoke it here! (But maybe one of the other proofs on that page avoids this problem?)

Comment: @HansLundmark We know that $$B(m,n) = \frac{\Gamma(m)\Gamma(n)}{\Gamma(m+n)} = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n-1}}{(1+x)^{m+n}} \, dx$$ Taking  $m + n = 1$ and using the given result, we can obtain the required result.

Comment: @HansLundmark sorry, I forgot about the final point in that answer (being the assumption of $\Gamma({\frac{1}{2}})$)

Comment: @CormAlan You can use the infinite product expression for the gamma function and sine function to prove this.

Comment: @tmwki Could you link that proof please? :) Can't find it

Comment: @CormAlan Check Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function on Gamma function. It has the proof of Euler's reflection formula.